# How to write a test class for a custom controller

Tags: unit-test

i'm a newbie in terms of apex programming. Where i not very sure how write a test class, with 75% coverage.

Comment: Start reading some documentation - https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods

Comment: This is a good start https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_error_handling.htm

Comment: <pre>
This will be a good start for beginner
</pre>
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

as your question relates to writing code, you should first go to developer.salesforce.com and look for further information on how to write testclasses. Test classes have been a mandatory part of code deployment in Salesforce to ensure that the code being deployed does not cause errors when it is run. 
The first thing to do is read this section: [Testing Custom Controllers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_error_handling.htm)

The next step is to head over to the Force.com's Developers User Guide and read the section on [Testing Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing.htm).

Lastly, read this about code coverage: [Code Coverage Best practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_code_coverage_best_pract.htm)

Once you have started writing your test class and run into problems you can then post your issue with sample code here.

Good luck!